# Microsoft Visual studio 2019's Git extension doesnt fetch from other remotes

Tags: git, gitlab, visual-studio-2019, git-remote, git-fetch

I use Visual Studio 2019 with Git source control. My repository has two remote, an **Origin** for inside office repository which stored in local aria network, and another remote which addresses to the   **Gitlab**. I use out of the box Git feature for sync remote repositories. The problem is when I fetch or pull  from the origin, it works correctly, but when I try to fetch from the Gitlab remote, it doesn't work without any notification and message. Therefore I have to use command line git for fetching. I will happy if anybody solve this problem or has the same problem and shares experiences.

***tested IDE is: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.5***

Comment: Is `remote.gitlab.fetch` set in git config?

Comment: @ElpieKay I think yes. because it works correctly from cli  ` git pull gitlab master `

Comment: @ElpieKay I checked there is remote.gitlab.fetch

Comment: also **push** command from extension acts the same.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same question.